# SQL Server is reading only first row from valid JSON

Tags: json, sql-server-2016, azure-sql-database

My JSON is like below. This JSON is read by ADF without problem and imports all rows.

```
{"Row":{"Col1":"Val1", "Col2":"Val2"}}
{"Row":{"Col1":"Val1", "Col2":"Val2"}}
{"Row":{"Col1":"Val1", "Col2":"Val2"}}
```

However when I read this from SQL using below query, it returns only first record.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@JSONDATA, '$')
with (
    Col1 varchar(25) '$.Row.Col1'
);
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to change your JSON data structure like below. Yours is also not valid JSON. Try any online JSON validators to see the difference.

Correct one would be:

```
[
  {"Col1":"Val1", "Col2":"Val2"},
  {"Col1":"Val1", "Col2":"Val2"},
  {"Col1":"Val1", "Col2":"Val2"}
]
```

As yours is simply an object it will probably get just one row.  [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-openjson-with-an-explicit-schema-sql-server) uses `OPENJSON` like this too.

After you changed it to an array you have to edit your query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@JSONDATA, '$')
with (
    Col1 varchar(25) '$.Col1',
    Col2 varchar(25) '$.Col2'
);
```

It gets all of the rows now as in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: thanks! But the JSON is big one coming from external source where we dont have control. Wondering how MS Azure ADF is able to load this JSON.

Comment: @HemantChandurkar ,You can preserve your schema, just convert to array
`[{"Row":{"Col1":"Val1", "Col2":"Val2"}},
{"Row":{"Col1":"Val1", "Col2":"Val2"}},
{"Row":{"Col1":"Val1", "Col2":"Val2"}}]`

Answer (score 3):

If you can't change the input format to use an array, and you know that the objects are delimited by newlines, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` to get each into its own row:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(value, '$.Row.Col1') 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@JSONDATA, CHAR(10))
```

Or you can preprocess the input so it *is* parsable by `OPENJSON`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(N'[' + REPLACE(@JSONDATA, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ',') + N']')
WITH (
    Col1 VARCHAR(25) '$.Row.Col1'
);
```

If you have no row delimiters, I'm not sure this can be done cleanly in T-SQL.