Select array data in JSON string
I have some problem where I cannot return all array data in the following JSON string
'{"ShipmentData": [{"consignee_name":"Test Sender","consignee_contact_number":"(+852)465456456","consignee_address":"Caloocan, Metro Manila, Philippines, 456 Apartment","consignee_3level_location":"PHILIPPINES METRO MANILA CALOOCAN","consignee_city_name":"CALOOCAN","service_type":"Express","consignee_postal_code":"2345345345","shipment_tracking_id":"QC0123102700001-001","senderVATNumber":null,"recipientVATNumber":null,"instructions":null,"volume_weight":0.2000,"gross_weight":1.0000,"shipment_reference_id":"[\"\"]","package_id":"a1c5664b-09db-4973-a947-33af15d0f030","deliveryDuties":"Tax Paid by: Sender / Receiver","nonDeliveryInstructions":"Return     /     Destroy","sender_name":"Test Consignee","sender_contact_number":"(+63)54554","sender_address":"HongKong, Hong Kong, 123 Apartment","sender_3level_location":"HONG KONG HONG KONG HONG KONG","hub_code":null,"vendor_code":null,"sort_code":"Sort Code: - ATL "}], "CommodityData": [{"quantity":1,"commodity_name":"DOCUMENT"}], [{"quantity":2,"commodity_name":"DOCUMENT2"}]}'

Expected result is:
consignee_name | quantity  | SHIFT_ID
------------------------------------
Test Sender    | 1         | DOCUMENT
Test Sender    | 2         | DOCUMENT2

Here's my attempt
declare @json_string nvarchar(max) =  '{"ShipmentData": [{"consignee_name":"Test Sender","consignee_contact_number":"(+852)465456456","consignee_address":"Caloocan, Metro Manila, Philippines, 456 Apartment","consignee_3level_location":"PHILIPPINES METRO MANILA CALOOCAN","consignee_city_name":"CALOOCAN","service_type":"Express","consignee_postal_code":"2345345345","shipment_tracking_id":"QC0123102700001-001","senderVATNumber":null,"recipientVATNumber":null,"instructions":null,"volume_weight":0.2000,"gross_weight":1.0000,"shipment_reference_id":"[\"\"]","package_id":"a1c5664b-09db-4973-a947-33af15d0f030","deliveryDuties":"Tax Paid by: Sender / Receiver","nonDeliveryInstructions":"Return     /     Destroy","sender_name":"Test Consignee","sender_contact_number":"(+63)54554","sender_address":"HongKong, Hong Kong, 123 Apartment","sender_3level_location":"HONG KONG HONG KONG HONG KONG","hub_code":null,"vendor_code":null,"sort_code":"Sort Code: - ATL "}], "CommodityData": [{"quantity":1,"commodity_name":"DOCUMENT"}], [{"quantity":2,"commodity_name":"DOCUMENT2"}]}'

select
    sd.consignee_name,
    cd.quantity,
    cd.commodity_name
from 
    OPENJSON(@json_string, '$.ShipmentData')
WITH (
    consignee_name NVARCHAR(100) '$.consignee_name'
) AS sd
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(@json_string, '$.CommodityData')
WITH (
    quantity INT '$.quantity',
    commodity_name NVARCHAR(100) '$.commodity_name'
) AS cd

but it only give me 1 row of CommodityData.
Your help is really appreciated. Thanks!

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44927381/sql-server-is-reading-only-first-row-from-valid-json

It is a weird JSON: ""CommodityData": [{"quantity":1,"commodity_name":"DOCUMENT"}], [{"quantity":2,"commodity_name":"DOCUMENT2"}]}'" Why do you have comma-separated arrays?

@Alex wow nice catch! This is the issue, the string was too long and I didn't manage to see it. Thanks! it should be working now. Changed it to: "CommodityData": [{"quantity":1,"commodity_name":"DOCUMENT"}, {"quantity":2,"commodity_name":"DOCUMENT2"}]}

Your JSON is not well-formed. After I fixed it, everything is working.
Check it out below.
SQL
declare @json_string nvarchar(max) = 
N'{
    "ShipmentData": [
        {
            "consignee_name": "Test Sender",
            "consignee_contact_number": "(+852)465456456",
            "consignee_address": "Caloocan, Metro Manila, Philippines, 456 Apartment",
            "consignee_3level_location": "PHILIPPINES METRO MANILA CALOOCAN",
            "consignee_city_name": "CALOOCAN",
            "service_type": "Express",
            "consignee_postal_code": "2345345345",
            "shipment_tracking_id": "QC0123102700001-001",
            "senderVATNumber": null,
            "recipientVATNumber": null,
            "instructions": null,
            "volume_weight": 0.2,
            "gross_weight": 1.0,
            "shipment_reference_id": "[\"\"]",
            "package_id": "a1c5664b-09db-4973-a947-33af15d0f030",
            "deliveryDuties": "Tax Paid by: Sender / Receiver",
            "nonDeliveryInstructions": "Return     /     Destroy",
            "sender_name": "Test Consignee",
            "sender_contact_number": "(+63)54554",
            "sender_address": "HongKong, Hong Kong, 123 Apartment",
            "sender_3level_location": "HONG KONG HONG KONG HONG KONG",
            "hub_code": null,
            "vendor_code": null,
            "sort_code": "Sort Code: - ATL "
        }
    ],
    "CommodityData": [
        {
            "quantity": 1,
            "commodity_name": "DOCUMENT"
        },
        {
            "quantity": 2,
            "commodity_name": "DOCUMENT2"
        }
    ]
}'

SELECT
    sd.consignee_name,
    cd.quantity,
    cd.commodity_name
from 
    OPENJSON(@json_string, '$.ShipmentData')
WITH (
    consignee_name NVARCHAR(100) '$.consignee_name'
) AS sd
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(@json_string, '$.CommodityData')
WITH (
    quantity INT '$.quantity',
    commodity_name NVARCHAR(100) '$.commodity_name'
) AS cd;

Output



consignee_name
quantity
commodity_name




Test Sender
1
DOCUMENT


Test Sender
2
DOCUMENT2



